# How to convert all data in dataframe column to dates [Python/Pandas]

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, pandas

I have a long list of dates, currently of dtype object.

```
.
.
22/05/2014
22/05/2014
0
22/05/2014
.
.
```

I want to plot these dates against some numerical data, in a 3D plot if possible.

Whether dates need converting or not it would be nice to know:

1. How can I convert the list of date strings (for large dataset)
2. How do I deal with the random "0"s in my dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest treating the `0` as missing values when reading the data, so it will be converted to missing datatime value in the end:

```
In [67]:

df=pd.read_clipboard(header=None, na_values=['0'])
print df
            0
0  22/05/2014
1  22/05/2014
2         NaN
3  22/05/2014
In [68]:

pd.to_datetime(df[0])
Out[68]:
0   2014-05-22
1   2014-05-22
2          NaT
3   2014-05-22
Name: 0, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Your 3rd question is too vague. Improved it or the others may want to vote to close your question on the ground of being too board.